# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Webmasters breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  6         31
Users destroyed                                 258          0
Users deleted                                    10          0
Users contacted                                  15          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           478        344
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue              234         81
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        266         85
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue              326        127
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue             1,705      1,124
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              496        146
Tags merged                                       3          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             4          0
Tag synonyms created                              4          0
Revisions redacted                                2          0
Questions unprotected                             1          0
Questions reopened                              167          0
Questions protected                              40         44
Questions migrated                              103          0
Questions merged                                  2          0
Questions flagged⁴                                2        798
Questions closed                              1,935          3
Question flags handled⁴                         378        422
Posts unlocked                                    3         24
Posts undeleted                                  36         27
Posts locked                                     20        252
Posts deleted⁵                                  797      1,808
Posts bumped                                      0      1,112
Comments undeleted                               49          0
Comments flagged                                  0      1,044
Comments deleted⁶                             1,090      1,176
Comment flags handled                           289        755
Bounties canceled                                 1          0
Answers flagged                                   5      1,170
Answer flags handled                            853        322
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...